# Почему глобальные переменные инициализируются нулем, а локальные - мусором по умолчанию?

Tags: c++, c, переменные, global-variables, локальные-переменные

Почему глобальные и статические переменные инициализируются нулем, а локальные - рандомными значениями по умолчанию?

Comment: В этом нет никакого «тайного умысла». Просто так сложилось исторически. Если вам нужно, чтобы локальная переменная инициализировалась нулём, вы всегда можете добавить явный  инициализатор. Если первое, что вы делаете после объявления переменной — это присваиваете ей какое-нибудь значение, то зачем тратить ресурсы процессора на бесполезную инициализацию? Часть философии языка — «Не платить за то, что не используется». Как-то так.

Comment: Возможно, вам просто так повезло. Насколько я понимаю ничем они не инициализируются, просто уж как попадёт, что было в этой области памяти до выделения под ваши объекты.

Comment: Вы правы! Мудро сказано

Comment: @wololo: Расходы на ненужную инициализацию были бы причиной 15 лет назад, но сейчас оптимизаторы поумнее всё-таки: https://godbolt.org/z/z4bfKKa7f. Так что платить не приходится.

Comment: Я бы задал вопрос по другому --  зачем  глобальные переменные **вообще чем-то инициализуются**?

Comment: @VladD, да, порой для компилятора отсутствие необходимости инициализации очевидно. С другой стороны можно в цикле объявить массив на пару килобайт,  и передавать указатель на него в функцию, определённую в другой единице трансляции. Будь нулевая инициализация обязательной, пришлось бы на каждой итерации цикла обнулять массив, даже если в этом нет необходимости. Ну, или нужен прям совсем умный компилятор.

Comment: @wololo: Ну, стоит лишь заинлайнить функцию, и сразу становится всё хорошо. Даже у MSVC есть опция whole program optimization

Comment: @avp, кстати да, а есть вообще ответ на этот вопрос?

Comment: @n1kzzz, один ответ очевиден -- Керниган с Ритчи так решили. Почему именно так? Я точно не знаю, но думаю, что инициализация статиков не нулями это практически бесплатно, инициализация локальных стоит лишних усилий. Почему надо что-то делать с неинициализированными статиками? Наверное по аналогии с другими все же чем-то прописать, вот и решили нулями

Comment: @avp: Вероятно, ОС инициализировала сегменты нулями, так что инициализация статиков могла быть бесплатной.

Comment: @VladD, не думаю, что прото-unix (тот, что был еще на асме (BCPL?) и для развития которого они делалиСи) читал bss с внешнего устройства. Просто нет смысла. Сейчас в bare-metal инициализацию bss нулями пишут в начале стартового кода (ну, наверное кто как, может у кого-то в самом первом загрузчике, который зашит в ROM это сделано, но проще из стартового кода, поскольку он встраивается линкером и символы (bss_start, bss_end, stack и т.п. там бесплатно видны))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Локальные переменные создаются при вызове функции и хранятся на стеке(не всегда, например они могут помещаться в регистры). Соответственно при каждом вызове функции они заново помещаются в стек и обычно принимают значение того объекта, который лежал по этому адресу ранее, я не могу сказать точно с чем это связано, скорее всего это сделано для оптимизации. А вот глобальные и статические переменные каждый раз не пересоздаются, они существуют с самого начала выполнения программы и имеют фиксированную ячейку памяти, соответственно проще всего их будет инициализировать нулевым значением. По идее их можно инициализировать не только нулем, но ничего не поменяется в том плане, что их значение всегда будет оставаться фиксированным.

Answer (score 1):

У бинаря во многих ОСях есть несколько различных секций(еще их могут называть сегментами):

1. Секция .text - для исполняемого кода
2. Секция .data - для инициализированных данных
3. Секция .bss - для неинилизированных данных
4. Секция стека - писать, что это такое, долго, но главное понять, что в основном она используется для реализации возрата управления из функций, для передачи в нее аргументов и для хранения в функции локальных переменных

По итогу, что имеем:
Все локальные переменные хранятся на стеке, а так как он может использоваться и для много чего другого, то при выделении памяти в этом месте, он может содержать в себе что угодно(значения локальных переменных, оставшиеся после работы других функций и т.д). Поэтому неинициализированные локальные переменные содержат в себе мусор.
Другая ситуация с глобальными и статическими переменными, если они инициализированы, то они хранятся в секции .data. Если они неинициализированы, то тогда компилятор помещает их в секцию .bss - а в ней при старте программы хранятся нули, вот и получаем, что неинициализированные глобальные и статические переменные содержат 0